# JMeter Load testing of API in AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter

I am new to JMeter so getting confused in conducting a test. My test scenario 
1) Hit a REST URL in API Gateway
2) Request should be 100 requests per seconds
3) Conduct the test for 2 hrs
4) Evaluate the error / success percentage
What parameters should I put to achieve this combination ? Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) to your Test Plan and configure it like:

   - Put `${__tstFeedback(jp@gc - Throughput Shaping Timer,500,1000,10)}` into "Target Concurrency" input.
   - Put `120` into "Hold Target Rate Time (min)" input
2. Add [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) Sampler to your Test Plan and configure it to send request to the REST URL
3. You might also need to add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#MIME_type)
4. Add [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin) as a child of your HTTP Request sampler and configure it like:

   - Start RPS: `100`
   - End RPS: `100`
   - Duration: `7200`
5. Run your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.csv
   ```
6. Open JMeter GUI, add i.e. [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener to your test plan and see the metrics. You can also generate a [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) to see extended results and charts .

Comment: Hi , thanks for you reply. Can you pls tell me what is the meaning of **${__tstFeedback(jp@gc - Throughput Shaping Timer,500,1000,10)}**. I did all the steps mentioned above but when I am running the jmeter command it is not ending. I initially tested with 60 sec but it went long than that , also the csv file was of 0 KB. Is there something I have missed?

Comment: Do I need to keep  _Hold Target Rate Time (min)_ and _Duration_ same. I want to test for 60 sec first and the for 2 hrs ? Pls suggest

Comment: If you  have only one request - it's better to have the same value. You might want to set different values as Throughput Shaping Timer's [scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) can be limited to one or several samplers while Concurrency Thread Group duration is "global" and applied to all its children in any case.